# Constraint Layout viewed on xml design view is not same when run on a device

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I'm using constraint layout to minimize use of LinearLayouts but I can't understand why what I see on preview is not what it actually looks like when run on an emulator or on a physical device.

[This is preview layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJoi2.png)

[this is what looks like when run on a device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IocZ.png)

this is my xml:

---

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                                             
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/conts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@android:color/white"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"                                        
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_header"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPg1_2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/conts"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tokhang_header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPg1_0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="As of"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_header"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.782"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="-2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPg1_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tokang_pg1_1antidrugopn"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:paddingLeft="55dp"
    android:text="700"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textScaleX="1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPg1_2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_header"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="-2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPg1_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tokang_pg1_2drugpers"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="700"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textScaleX="1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPg1_3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPg1_1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="-2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPg1_3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tokang_pg1_3drugpersdied"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="700"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textScaleX="1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPg1_4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPg1_2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="-2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPg1_4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tokang_pg1_4housevisited"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:text="700"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textScaleX="1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPg1_3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFF4444"
    android:shadowDx="-2"
    android:shadowDy="-2"
    android:shadowRadius="1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="122dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPg1_4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tokhang_footer" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and everytime i open the xml the layout changes or gets misaligned that i have to undo with me doing any changes. It seems constrain layout is unstable or it's me unstable being a newbie. 
Do you have an idea of what's happening ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There are multiple problems here. You cannot set `android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"` and expect that it looks the same on each device. `android:layout_marginRight="150dp"` same thing. Maybe it looks on your preview because you've matched the dimensions, but practically it won't match any display out there. 
I'd suggest trying to build it without ConstraintLayout first, after that try to practice ConstraintLayout version (or convert that layout in android studio).
So,first step would be to remove hardcoded values with dynamic relations and then to check the bugs

Comment: thanks i rewrite my xml not using constraintlayout.